# Numbers inside TextView getting reversed when formatted in RTL

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

Numbers inside `TextView` are getting reversed when formatted in RTL. 
When numbers are at the end of a text inside a `TextView` they getting reversed. How can I solve this programmatically?

As an example, the numbers below are reversed:

[image]

They should be displayed like:

[image]

Comment: Sample code of what you did will help understand the problem and also make solving it easier

Answer (score 9):

**The misunderstand:**
Digits in RTL languages like ARABIC should be written from RTL with the arabic digits to avoid any problems i.e: "تم إرسال رسالة نصية للرقم ١٢٣٤" Note that I wrote "رسالة نصية" NOT "SMS رسالة".

**The problem and it's solution:**
[Mixing more than one direction languages](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Characters) required more steps, you need to tell the system "hey this is RTL word, add as it to sequence".
[So you may need to do this implicitly](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Implicit_Directional_Marks), i.e:

`\u200f + تم إرسال رسالة نصية إلى + number`

**Consider StringBuilder:** It's very painful for developer to develop something for RTL language using *plus*(+) notation, this much confusing and error prone.

A better way:

```
builder.append("\u061C").append(" تم إرسال رسالة نصية لـ").append("\u200E").append("+0123456789")
```

[**Consider BidiFormatter:**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BidiFormatter.html) Utility class for formatting text for display in a potentially opposite-directionality context without garbling

Example:

```
String text = "{0} تم إرسال رسالة نصية لـ ";
String phone = BidiFormatter.getInstance().unicodeWrap("+961 01 234 567");
String result = MessageFormat.format(text,phone);
```

Now, `result` will be formatted properly.

[More examples on how BidiFormatter work.](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter)

Comment: Neither did the StringBuilder nor did the \u200f method work.

Comment: Can you give me an example over using BidiFormatter? It worked, but I won't accept an answer with a link as links are prone to being killed at any minute.

Comment: @Ab_ Can you provide how you used the unicode code, it should work, for example when start arabic letter use `u\061C` and when start english letter use `u\200E`. in the same text

Comment: @Ab_ i I added typical examples for StringBuilder and BidiFormatter

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent the reversing of numbers for TextView when formatted in RTL, just specify `android:textDirection="ltr"` property for that specific TextView inside XML file. It will display number in the usual order.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

android:supportsRtl="false" in manifest file

and android:gravity="start" in your layout.

Comment: `supportsRtl` will make the entire project LTR, which is NOT what I want.

Answer (score -2):

set the textview gravity to start

```
android:gravity="start"
```

Comment: it dosent solve the problem, the problem is not the aligmend the alignment is fine, there is a special case when there is number at the end.