# Change specific paragraph direction in android text view with spans

Tags: android, textview, bidi

I want to change **specific** paragraphs direction through code with spans in android text view

Here is what i tried :

I tried adding LTR or RTL unicode 
but this approach changes the text length which i cant do since its a book reader kind of app

```
 /**
 * Unicode "Left-To-Right Embedding" (LRE) character.
 */
private static final char LTR = '\u202A';

/**
 * Unicode "Right-To-Left Embedding" (RLE) character.
 */
private static final char RTL = '\u202B';

/**
 * Unicode "Left-To-Right Mark" (LRM) character.
 */
private static final char INSIDE_LTR = '\u200E';

/**
 * Unicode "Right-To-Left Mark" (RLM) character.
 */
private static final char INSIDE_RTL = '\u200F';
```

I also tried changing the text direction through

```
android:textDirection
```

The issue is this changes all paragrapghs directon according to the following

```
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL = 2;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG = 1;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG_LTR = 6;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG_RTL = 7;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_INHERIT = 0;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_LOCALE = 5;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR = 3;
  public static final int TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL = 4;
```

I also tried [LocaleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LocaleSpan)

but it had no effect on text direction

i want to do it like spans set from X to y To be LTR or RTL ,
any idea ?

Comment: I think you want to combine RTL language with LTR language in the same line..
I think this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403418/11161537

Comment: @IbrahimAli Yes i want to do something like that but the answer in the link adds unicodes which i cant do as i stated in the question , he is also using BidiFormatter's UnicodeWrap method which also adds unicodes in the text

Comment: There are many approaches, And the worked one was the BidiFormatter's approach.
Did you tried it ?

Comment: @IbrahimAli yes i tried it but adding unicodes changes text length which i cant do as its a book reader app with rules applied to text with their text index , so adding unicodes changes text index which will ruin the rules applied to text like bold , left alignment , right alignment etc...

Comment: How did you receive the text? I suppose you got it from API JSON/XML as HTML format.
is that right?

Comment: @IbrahimAli i have the text as plain text in a file and the span rules in another files